# Compare large csv files inside 2 folders and print exact difference along with the line number in python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, compare, diff

I have to compare large csv files inside 2 different folders. The files are stored in same name inside these folders. After comparing I need to print the file name, line number and the field which is different. If any line is missing in one of the csv's then I need to print that as well with filename, line number.

I have a code which could print only the field which is different but not the line number between the two given files.

```
import csv
import itertools
f1= open("file1.csv")
f2= open("file2.csv")
csv_f1= csv.reader(f1)
csv_f2= csv.reader(f2)
for row1, row2 in zip(csv_f1,csv_f2):
    if row1 != row2:
        print(set(row1)-set(row2))
```

Please help in extending this to folder level and print file name and line number along with the field causing difference. Also I need to print file name and line number for missing lines.

I have tried using line_num function on csv.reader part, but it is returning some other result instead of line number. Any function to find the line number along with difference would be of great help. Thank you.

Edit: I am posting the query and files below as asked by @Adrian

```
import csv
import itertools
f1= open("D:/Users/KPriya4/Downloads/csv1.csv")
f2= open("D:/Users/KPriya4/Downloads/csv2.csv")
csv_f1= csv.reader(f1)
csv_f2= csv.reader(f2)
line = 0
for row1, row2 in zip(csv_f1,csv_f2):
    if row1 != row2:
        if not row1:
            print("file1.csv: Row " + str(line) + " is empty")
            continue
        if not row2:
            print("file2.csv: Row " + str(line) + " is empty")
            continue
        print(set(row1)-set(row2))
        print(line)
    line += 1
```

[File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZUgu.png)

[File 2 with difference highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvXIY.png)

Row 5 in file1 with first name as 'Carlos' is missing in file2.

When I run the code, I get the following output.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PHJf.png)

This has another line too (line 6) which does not have difference.

Forgive me for not posting image as such asI am not allowed to attach an image, it is posting as links only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new information that you provided I was able to put this together. The problem with the code you used, is that as both files have different length, when you zip them together the length of the zip will be the one of the list with less items, so you will loose information. Also, as there are no blank rows, you need to iterate over the other list to check if the item you are looking for is in a different position. As your CSV files contain an ID field I assumed this will be unique, and I iterate over it:

```
import csv
import itertools
f1= open("file1.csv")
f2= open("file2.csv")
csv_f1= csv.reader(f1)
csv_f2= csv.reader(f2)

csv_f1 = list(csv_f1)
csv_f2 = list(csv_f2)

line1 = 0
line2 = 0
for row1 in range(0,len(csv_f1)):
    found = False
    # This checks if a row with the same ID exists in the other file and compares them if it does
    for row2 in range(0,len(csv_f2)):
        if csv_f1[row1][1] == csv_f2[row2][1]:
            found = True
            if csv_f1[row1] != csv_f2[row2]:
                print("Line " + str(line1) + " from file 1 and line " + str(line2) + " from file 2 have same ID but different data")
                print(set(csv_f1[row1])-set(csv_f2[row2]))
    if not found:
        print("Line " + str(line1) + " from file 1 is not in file 2")
    line2 += 1
    line1 += 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have 2 files in which, line 1 and line 3 after header are having differences and line 5 is present in file1 but not in file2.When I am trying this code, it is not considering "if not" statements at all. Instead it is printing differences in line 1 and 3, line 5 which is missing in file2 (printed in shuffled order, not the original order of file). But it is also printing line 6(entire line in shuffled order) which is same in both files. But the next line(line7) which is also same in both files is not printed.
Am I missing something so wrong line also gets printed?

Comment: @Pri31 can you paste the whole code and an example of each csv file in your question? I just tried the code and works fine for me

Comment: I have attached the images of files and output along with the code as an edit to my question.

Comment: Question, in the CSV file2, when you mean line5 is missing, is there a blank row on the CSV? Or is it just a different line there?

Comment: It is a whole separate line which is present in file 1 at line number 6 (5th row after header with first name column as 'carole'). It is missing in file 2. That gets printed in the output. But the line next to that also gets printed, which is not supposed to print as it is similar in both files.

Comment: I see. I updated my answer and modified all the code. Is working for me, give it a try!

Comment: Yes it works now. Thanks a lot. Do we have any way to auto compare all csv files present inside 2 folders, given the file names are same inside both folders?

Comment: I believe you can store the names of the files in an array and loop through it opening one file at a time! If my solution is good enough please mark it as accepted answer!